# Find all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that make a $60$ degrees angle with vector $r$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $r = (1,1)$. Find all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that make a $60$-degree angle with vector $r$.

My attempt:
$$v = (x,y)$$

$$\begin{align} r\cdot u =(1,1)\cdot(x,y)=x+y &= \|r\|\|v\|\cos60^\circ \\
&=(\sqrt2)(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})/2
(\sqrt2)(x+y) \\ 
&= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}2x^2 + 4xy + 2y^2 \\
&= x^2 + y^2 x^2 + 4xy + y^2 \\
&= 0\end{align}$$

I'm having trouble finding the values of $x$ and $y$ here.

Comment: Are you asking how to continue with your approach or for another approach that solves the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing this as a second degree equation $ax^2 +bx+c$ with $a=1,b=4y,c=y^2$, you get
$$
x=\frac{-4y\pm\sqrt{16y^2-4y^2}}{2}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbf r=(1,1)$ we could use the rotation matrix $\mathbf R(\theta)=\left[\begin{array}{r,r}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{array}\right]$ to find out the vectors that make $60º$ with $\mathbf r$.

Then we can calculate the vectors we want:

$$\mathbf R(60º)\mathbf r^T=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^T=\mathbf c$$ where $n\mathbf c, n\in\mathbb R^+$ are the vectors that satisfie what you look for. Also $n\mathbf R(-60º)\mathbf r^T$ will be the other part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that is less algebraic but more intuitive.

First, find the direction angle of vector $r$, namely 
$$\theta=\mathrm{atan2}(1,1)=\arctan(1/1)=45°$$

Then we want vectors with the direction angles $\phi+1=45°+60°$ and $\phi_2=45°-60°$. If the magnitude of the vector is $d$ then the vectors with $\phi_1$ are

$$(d\cos \phi_1, d\sin \phi_1)=(d\cos(45°+60°), d\sin(45°+60°))$$

and similarly for $\phi_2$. Use the angle addition and subtraction formulas for sine and cosine to get the exactly values for those vectors.

Note that there are two families of vectors in the result. Also note that this method works well for $\mathbb R^2$ but not for higher dimensions.